# How to exit python script inside jenkins pipeline without ending the pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, exit

So i have a jenkins pipeline that calls a python script that has exit(0) at the end of it.
After the python script i have some more groovy code, but the pipeline ends successfully after the exit(0) and before even reaching the groovy code.
The problem seems to be that the "exit(0)" ends the whole pipeline.
Is there a way to end the python script without ending the whole pipeline? thnx!

Comment: What is `exit0`? It's not a Python built-in so it's hard to guess what it does. Python `sys.exit(0)` should not end the pipeline.

Comment: I meant exit(0), my bad!

Comment: `exit()` is intended for use in the interactive shell, not in programs. Use `sys.exit()` in programs.